# Make a request using alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

How would I make this curl request using alamofire?

```
curl -v 'https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi?api_key=API_Key&event=%5B%7B%22user_id%22%3A%22datamonster%40gmail.com%22%2C%20%22event_type%22%3A%22watch_tutorial%22%2C%20%22user_properties%22%3A%7B%22Cohort%22%3A%22Test%20A%22%7D%2C%20%22country%22%3A%22United%20States%22%2C%20%22ip%22%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%2C%20%22time%22%3A1396381378123%7D%5D'
```

Or this one:

```
curl --data 'api_key=API_Key' --data-urlencode 'event=[{"user_id":"datamonster@gmail.com", "event_type":"watch_tutorial", "user_properties":{"Cohort":"Test A"}, "country":"United States", "ip":"127.0.0.1", "time":1396381378123}]' https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi
```

Here is a little more information about what I am looking to do.

https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204771828-HTTP-API

Right now I am just taking the parameters and doing this:

```
var evnetProps = Parameters()
evnetProps["event_type"] = eventName
evnetProps["user_id"] = "hi@testing.com"
evnetProps["user_properties"] = userProperties

var parameters:Parameters = Parameters()
parameters["event"] = evnetProps
parameters["api_key"] = self.shared.apiKey


Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: defaultHeaders).responseJSON {response in
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: "not working" == compile error, runtime error, broken URL, bad results, ...?

Comment: it is just returning this: "missing argument event"